# How to realize browser-to-browser communication (allowed server as bridge) without Flash/Java?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, p2p, file-sharing

I've been looking for this question and found services, wich work with the Adobe Cirrus (for example FilesOverMiles). Also there are services, which work without Flash, and they also seem to be p2p. Is this true? For example, one of this services is [justbeamit](http://justbeamit.com/). There is no Flash or Java and everything works as required. How it is realized? And how it can be realized at the server-side?

javascript sources of  justbeamit [here](http://justbeamit.com/static/js/jbi.JustBeamIt.js)

Comment: If server-side mediation is an option you could take a look at http://www.ape-project.org/.

Comment: That "justbeamit" site just does a file transfer to a server, then back out to a client. It's not browser-to-browser.

Answer (score 0):

I used APE to do some real-time stuff : http://www.ape-project.org/
That's a channel-based javascript framework. I don't think that's the best tool to share files, but it'a great one to do some one-to-many or many-to-many communication.